# abrir una nueva ventana al dar clic en un button en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Estoy intentando crear una nueva función para un aplicativo web que he estado creando en C#, lo que requiero hacer es que al dar clic en un `button` llamado `guardar`, se realice la acción de guardar los datos y aparte de eso se abra una nueva pestaña en el navegador con un informe que se construido, de momento tengo la función de que al dar clic en guardar me redirige al informe

```
Response.Redirect("../Visor/ConstruirReporte.aspx?Reporte=CRE9&id=" + TextBoxRecibo.Text);
```

como podria hacer para indicarle que se me abra ese informe en una nueva pestaña

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abrir un nuevo tab es una instrucción del lado del cliente, no del lado del servidor.

lo que debes de hacer es instruirle al servidor que escriba una función del lado del cliente para abrir una nueva pestaña

```
   Response.Write("<script> window.open('" + pageurl + "','_blank'); </script>");
```

Comment: Gracias he logrado lo que quería probar